# Strategies of inheritance in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I new to JPA , so the question of beginner:

1. Why Hibernate Provider creates second table with employees_employees ? 
   What code in mine example is the cause of creating the second table ?
2. Why manager_id column become fk to id column from employees ? Why do i need fk in single table strategy ?
3. Why the primary key (Gold color from screenshot) created ?
4. In the second table `employees_employees` was created department_id as fk to id in employees table, why ?
5. Any resources from Internet for understanding this , will be HelpFul!

[image]

Employee:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "employees")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "test" , discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Employee {

public Employee(int id, String name, String lastname, double salary, String spec) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.specialization = spec;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", salary=" + salary +
            ", spec='" + specialization + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastname;

@Column(name = "salary")
private double salary;

@Column (name = "specialization")
private String specialization;

public Manager getManager() {
    return manager;
}

public void setManager(Manager manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Manager manager;

public Employee(){}
}
```

Manager:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("M")
public class Manager extends Employee{

public Manager(){}


public Set<Departments> getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Set<Departments> department) {
    this.department = department;
}

public String getManager_country() {
    return manager_country;
}

public void setManager_country(String manager_country) {
    this.manager_country = manager_country;
}

public String getManager_address() {
    return manager_address;
}

public void setManager_address(String manager_address) {
    this.manager_address = manager_address;
}

public String getManager_experience() {
    return manager_experience;
}

public void setManager_experience(String manager_experience) {
    this.manager_experience = manager_experience;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Manager{" +
            "department=" + department +
            ", manager_address='" + manager_address + '\'' +
            ", manager_experience='" + manager_experience + '\'' +
            ", manager_country='" + manager_country + '\'' +
            ", id=" + id +
            '}';
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER , cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE} )
private Set<Departments> department;

//private Employee employee;

public Manager(String manager_experience,String manager_address, String manager_country) {

    this.manager_experience = manager_experience;
    this.manager_address = manager_address;
    this.manager_country = manager_country;
}

@Column(name = "experience")
private String manager_experience;

@Column(name = "address")
private String manager_address;

@Column(name = "country")
private String manager_country;

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "manager_id" ,insertable = false , updatable = false)
private int id;
}
```

Departments:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("D")
public class Departments extends Manager{

public String getSales() {
    return sales;
}

public void setSales(String sales) {
    this.sales = sales;
}

public String getCostumer_support() {
    return costumer_support;
}

public void setCostumer_support(String costumer_support) {
    this.costumer_support = costumer_support;
}

public String getDevelopers() {
    return developers;
}

public void setDevelopers(String developers) {
    this.developers = developers;
}

public String getSystem_administrators() {
    return system_administrators;
}

public void setSystem_administrators(String system_administrators) {
    this.system_administrators = system_administrators;
}

public String getAccounting_department() {
    return accounting_department;
}

public void setAccounting_department(String accounting_department) {
    this.accounting_department = accounting_department;
}

//private Manager manager;

@Column(name = "costumer_support_department" , unique = false, updatable = true , insertable = true , nullable = true)
private String costumer_support;

@Column(name = "developers_department" , unique = false, updatable = true , insertable = true , nullable = true)
private String developers;

@Column(name = "sys_admins_department" , unique = false, updatable = true , insertable = true , nullable = true)
private String system_administrators;

@Column(name = "accounting_department" , unique = false, updatable = true , insertable = true , nullable = true)
private String accounting_department;

@Column(name = "sales_department" , unique = false, updatable = true , insertable = true , nullable = true)
private String sales;

public Departments(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've chosen `SINGLE_TABLE` as the inheritance strategy, both `Employee` and `Manager` are stored in the same table.

1. By default, unidirectional one-to-many relationship (`Employee.manager` in your case) are represented by JPA with the aid of an additional join table (just like many-to-many relationships). In your case, it just happens to join the `employees` table with itself. If you want a foreign key in the source entity's table instead, you need to use `@JoinColumn`
2. This is related to point #1. Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish with the following code? `Manager` already has an id (coming from its parent entity)

   ```
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "manager_id" ,insertable = false , updatable = false)
   private int id;
   ```

Event if you switch to using `@JoinTable` there will still be a foreign key in the `employees` table (how else would you imagine the `Employee` - `Manager` relationship to be represented in the database?)

3. Due to the following piece of code:

   ```
   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;
   ```
4. Good question. I suppose its because `Department` is-a `Manager`, and JPA needs this somehow when `Employee.manager` actually points to a `Department`. Why would you make `Department` inherit from `Manager`? Isn't it more logical that `Department` has-a `Manager` (`@OneToOne/@ManyToOne`)? That would simplify things, you know
5. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Example_of_a_OneToMany_using_a_JoinTable_database
   https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance (These are really the top results in Google...)

EDIT

To implement the `Department` has-a `Manager` relationship, you want the following changes:

```
    @Entity
    public class Department {
        @Id
        private int id;

        @ManyToOne(mappedBy = "department")
        private Manager manager;
        ...
    }
```

`Department.manager` is not absolutely necessary, but I've included it in case you wanted a bi-directional relationship (I didn't notice there was a `Manager.department` field already in `Manager` the first time I read your code)

Comment: Well thanks for some important points from you, i am new to JPA and i 'Playing' with the creation of tables to understand the behavior.

Comment: 4. Yes department has a manager , can you make some change to mine code for such logic ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve. But surely your code looks bit weird.

1) table employees_employees got created as you have mentioned mapping between manager and department as one to many. One table strategy is for one to one mappings by default.

2) problem is you have 2 variables with same name id; one in employee table and another one in manager table.

3) is correct behavior. you have used @id annotation in employee class. Hence primary key got created.

4) as you have used single table strategy. super parent class on department is employee hence primary key column of department is same s that of employee. So department_id references to id of employee table.

5) tell us what you want to achieve and we can help you. Or go through hibernate tutorials.